# How to open app.config in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, app-config

I need to open app.config with a click of a button. I've been trying to find how to do this with no luck. How can I open the file itself so I could edit it?

Comment: You need to display content of config in your form?

Comment: Open as in "view text" or as in "read settings"?

Comment: @ChrisShao I need to open the file itself so i could edit the settings.

Comment: @EvaldasGrigaitis Bad, *bad*, **bad** idea!!

Comment: You can Iterate through the key/value collection, no problem.
But I can imagine, that It might be quite helpful/usable to edit some of those values in a settings dialogue. However, how to do it properly, so that the changed values are put properly in the place, they belong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to open the application configuration file itself **you're doing something wrong**.

If you need to access settings defined using Visual Studio's settings designer, use the automatic properties like

```
var value = Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName;
```

If you want to edit **user** settings, do the same thing and save:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName = Value;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

You can not modify **application settings** anyway. If the application is installed in `Program Files` you will not even be allowed to write the file back, as the `Program Files` folder is not writable to your application.

If the application is installed using `ClickOnce` you're also out of luck, as the settings file for user settings is named totally differently and is not even in the same location as your application's executable.

So this comes down to: **Do it right** and **keep your hands off app.config!**

Comment: You are suggesting on creating 2nd form so that user could input the settings and then save them? I thought that opening the config file itself would be easier.

Comment: Not only is it not easier, it is error prone, dangerous and in most cases not even possible. Yes, I'm suggesting to use a proper settings dialog.

Comment: Please re-read my answer, because I've added some stuff on why what you originally wanted to do may not even be possible.

Comment: @EvaldasGrigaitis asking users to edit XML is never easier, make sure you set your property types correctly, so application for any unchangeable setting that the application needs and user for anything that might change dependent on who is using it, .net automatically manages that in the background by overriding the app.config file with user.config so evening if you did change app.config it might not be the file you are using

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar is it possible to open and safely edit user.config then?

Comment: @EvaldasGrigaitis Just don't! It is *not hard* to simply go the way things were designed. Besides, as I said, in some cases you won't even be able to *find* the config file easily. Just provide a proper UI to the user and that's it.